# Reason for not calling the copy constructor?

Tags: c++

I know that copy constructor is called whenever the object was returned. In my below case copy construcotr has not called.

I browsed in internet and i came to know that compiler has followed `return value optimization`  technique.I belive due that Copy construtor is not called. Is this true ?

and how program control goes here?

// some code goes here

```
demo demo::display()
    {
        demo temp(10);
        temp.rate=45;
        return temp; //copy constructor is not called here
         }

 int main( )
    {
              demo obj1=obj1.display();
              return 0;
    }
```

Comment: "I know that copy constructor is called whenever the object was returned" - you don't know that, because it isn't true. Yes, it's NRVO.

Comment: "I belive due that Copy construtor is not called. Is this true ?" Yes, that is true. The object is constructed into `obj1` on the caller's side.

Comment: An accessible copy constructor (or a move constructor, since C++11) is *required* whenever an object is returned by value, but that doesn't mean it will be used. As you already found out, it can be optimized away.

Comment: @juanchopanza another scenario for calling the copy constructor is Class obj1=obj2; So, demo obj1=obj1.display(); is equal to something Obj1=returned_object. why here not called?

Comment: @jrok can u please give me some illustration that copy constructor should be called when returning object...

Comment: Your example is a perfectly fine illustration. Try to define a `private` copy constructor for `demo` and you'll see the compiler complaining. NRVO and RVO are *permitted*, not required. If copy constructor wouldn't be required, the code without it would compile depending on whether a compiler does NRVO or doesn't.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision

Answer (score 1):

Reason for this is compiler optimization as you know. It's waste of resources to make temp object then make copy of it, then place that copy in obj1, and then destroy temp. Instead, compiler know that obj1 will get value of temp so it actually creates object temp on same memory location where obj1 is. So nothing is copied and nothing is destroyed.
Constructor is also called only once, temp and obj1 are same object.
It's called Return Value Optimization or RVO.

And it's not wise to call function for not yet initialized object as you did.

There are situation where it can't be applied that way...
If you did this instead:

```
demo demo::display(int unknown)
{
    demo temp1(10);
    demo temp2(11);
    if(unknown) return temp1;
    else return temp2; 
}
```

Now, compiler doesn't know which of two object's will be returned, because that depends on argument of display function, so temp1 and temp2 will be created in display's scope. Then in runtime when it's known which of them will be returned it is going to be copied (guess where?) in exact same location where obj1 is.
Try this and you'll see that copy constructor is called.

Comment: COnfused with statement "actually creates object temp on same memory location where obj1 is."  The obj1 is under main scope. You have said that the temp object is created in the same memory location where obj1 is... so  temp object will be created in main scope.. Am i correct. In addition to that... the temp object you have mentioned is the temporary object created by the compiler. I belive it is not the temp object i have created under the display fuction. That temp object i have declared and temp you were talking is different

Comment: You are right in your first statement. temp is created in main scope. That is because compiler knows that obj1 is going to get value of temp, so why create temp in display scope, than copy that, than destroy that when temp can be created in main scope and save some CPU cycles. I hope you get the point, there is no need for temp to exist as separate object so compiler won't make it as separate object.

Comment: I have also edited my answer, I hope that it is now clear what's going on.

Comment: One more thing, in your example, there is actually no temporary object, temp is just another name for obj1 in this case, or any other object that is going to get return value of display().